# cakephp:how to insert values for hasmany relationship

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How can I make entries in my uploads table, this code is not working

this is my project array:

```
[Project] => Array ( [name] => Testproject [description] => TestDescription [Upload] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => testlink1 [Type] => link )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => testlink2
                                [Type] => link
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => testlink3
                                [Type] => link
                            )

                    )

)
```

I've written

```
foreach($this->data['Project']['Upload'] as $key=>$value) 
{
    $this->data['Upload'][$key]['project_id'] = $this->Project->id; 
    $this->data['Upload'][$key]['name'] = $value['name'];
    $this->data['Upload'][$key]['type'] = $value['Type'];
    $this->data['Upload'][$key]['created'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
    $this->data['Upload'][$key]['modified'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $this->Project->Upload->save($this->data['Upload'][$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the foreach. Just make shure, you have your associations right:

```
/app/models/project.php
var $hasMany = array('Upload');

/app/models/upload.php
var $belongsTo = array('Project');
```

If you then have your data-array like said above you can just use `$this->Project->saveAll($this->data)` for saving everything at once.

Have a look into the manual to get more information on saveAll and how to to save related data: [Saving related model data](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1032/Saving-Related-Model-Data-hasOne-hasMany-belongsTo)

Comment: I've to do more stuff on my form, so I had to add project first and then other things, anyhow this code worked for me:
for($i=0;$i < count($this->data['Project']['Upload']);$i++)
    {
     
     $this->Project->Upload->create();
     
     $insertData = array('project_id' => $this->Project->id, 
          'name' => $this->data['Project']['Upload'][$i]['name'], 
          'type' => $this->data['Project']['Upload'][$i]['Type'],
          'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
          'modified' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s') );

    
     
     $this->Project->Upload->save($insertData);
     
    }